# java code to read all lines of an input file, not just the first

Tags: java

I am working in a simple netbeans project designed to read data from a file. The file has 5 lines, each with two fields (one is to identify the item and the other the quantity of the item). My problem is when I run the program it only reads the first line (i.e. item #1 and its quantity), and ignores the other 4 lines. How do I get it to read all 5 (or any number) lines and not just the first one? Sorry, I know this must be elementary, I am just starting to learn  java and hoping someone can help educate me! Thanks!

As requested, here is the code I'm using (and for what it's worth, the first line is item 3, so in the printout, all return as 0 except part3total which returns its quantity of 50):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int snum;
    int quantity;
    int part1total, part2total, part3total,part4total, part5total;

    part1total = 0;
    part2total = 0;
    part3total = 0;
    part4total = 0;
    part5total = 0;

    InputFile orderinfo;        
    orderinfo = new InputFile("sprocketorders.txt");

    snum = orderinfo.readInt();
    quantity = orderinfo.readInt();


    switch(snum)
    {
        case 1:     part1total = part1total + quantity;
        break;
        case 2:     part2total = part2total + quantity;
        break;
        case 3:     part3total = part3total + quantity;
        break;
        case 4:     part4total = part4total + quantity;
        break;
        case 5:     part5total = part5total + quantity;
        break;
    }

    System.out.println(part1total);
    System.out.println(part2total);
    System.out.println(part3total);
    System.out.println(part4total);    
    System.out.println(part5total);
```

Comment: show us the code and we will tell you whats the problem

Comment: Can you share the code to get better help.

Comment: `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file, charset);`

Comment: @assylias Supergreat and uneducational at the same time :)

Comment: Show us your existing code and we'll tidy it up for you.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That surely hides the complexity. But using a FileReader or whatever hides a lot of low level complexity too!

Comment: @assylias Absolutely. But at least it teaches how to use loops :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If you're in a learning process, you should learn about loops before having to read file (IMHO). So I would go with a simpler and clearer code, so I would be using the "new" `Files.readAllLines`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm sure not! But that doesn't change the fact that I still value simpler code over using something that would teach him to use loops. He will have other opportunity to learn loops.

Comment: @Marc-Andre  OP is capable of reading the file that means OP should have covered `loops` already. Those are very basics and should be learned prior to file operation. What I think is OP is not aware of how to use loops while reading file.

Comment: @Smit You're probably right.

Comment: @Marc-Andre This discussion is beyond ridiculous. I have deleted all of my comments.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're starting at Java and your case is about reading *Only* the first line, I assume you're reading *just* the first line without any structure that *iterates* over the rest.

You can start by using a `while`. To put it in pseudocode (so you can sort it out and try it on your own), one alternative is to do this:

```
while(There are more lines to read) {
    Read next line
    Process line
}
```

Comment: +1 for the educational approach ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through all the lines.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   // print the line.
System.out.println(line);
}
br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
    File archivo = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        archivo = new File("example.txt");
        fr = new FileReader(archivo);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        // Lectura del fichero
        String linea;
        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(linea);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (null != fr) {
                fr.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: why you don't close bufferedReader ,is cause fileReader already close when you close it? Cause it's a decorator may be when you close bufferedReader fileReader it's closed i don't know if in that side is true. Besides yoda code detected.

Comment: Closing `br` automatyically closes `fr`. However, if the poster can use Java 7, using `Files.newBufferedReader` in a try-with-resources block is more efficient. `Files.readAllLines` is even more efficient, as long as the file is small.  if it's a long file, that method is dangerous. If only there were a `Iterable<String> fileIterableView` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use a BufferedReader to read the lines of a file.

Refer [below](http://www.cafeaulait.org/slides/sd2000east/javaio/56.html) for an example